# Draw an inset for two unrelated plots

Tags: tikz-pgf

Suppose I have the following voltage vs. time data set, recorded by a decent oscillosocpe:

[image: pic1]

As you can see, there is some very fast changes between t=0 and t=1 sec for this measurement.

So I recorded this physical phenomena again, but now on a shorter time window, so the noisy part can be seen better:

[image: pic2]

Good! I have two csv files that I can plot with pgfplots.

What I am asking is how to produce this figure:

[image: pic3, inset]

Using tikz's `spy` library, you can zoom in on a portion of a TikZ picture.

This drawing above is very similar in its appearance to tikz's `spy` tool, but it is made of two "completely unrelated" plots. `spy` is good only for making an inset of one plot.

Any one have an idea?

*Note:* These plots were created with [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) and Windows paint. If you want to post an answer then a circle spied by a triangle is good too. This wiggling unrealistic waveform is just for demonstration purpose, to clarify the idea.

Thanks!

**Update:**

I read now the tikz manual and came across the Coordinate transformations subsection (25.3).

I just ran the following code, to compile successfully:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
grid=major,
]
\addplot[samples=10,domain=0:2]{x^2-2};
\end{axis}
\begin{scope}[xshift=8em,yshift=-20em]
\begin{axis}[
grid=major,
]
\addplot[samples=10,domain=-3:2]{-x^2+2};
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\draw[red,thick] (0,0) -- (2,1); % <--- A decoration
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: two plots seperated]

So I got two different `axis` environments, separated one from the other by the `{scope}[xshift , yshift]`. Now I added a thick red line from (0,0) to (2,1) but those two coordinates are not sticking to the (first) plot coordinates system, as you can see from the axis ticks.

I changed that to

```
\draw[red,thick] (axis cs:0,0) -- (2,1);
```

and got an error

> Missing \endcsname inserted. 
> \pgfcrdmth@x  l.18 \draw[red,thick] (axis cs:0,0)
> -- (2,1); ?

So I need to give this coordinate system a name, so TeX know whom I refer to? How do I do that?

Comment: Instead of using the spy library, why not just plot the two plots, draw the rectangles, and then the diagonal lines connecting them?

Comment: @WillieWong Yeah I guess it is a solution. How can I align the two pictures, one slightly to the right and slightly to the bottom? And then, what are the coordinate specifications for drawing the lines and the two rectangles?

Comment: Accordingly, I changed the question's title.

Comment: I'm somewhat confident that this won't be possible using the `spy` tool as that works by enlarging parts of the already existing image. Thus as already has been noted, you should just draw the decorations yourself.

Comment: @Raven All right, I agree. I couldn't find an existing answer on how to align two such plots, and (better be parametrically) drawing those decorations. So that is the reason I came up with a new question.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330331/pgfplots-how-to-nest-and-scale-axis-environments and/or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146588/draw-lines-inside-tikz-plot-exported-from-matlab-independent-of-coordinate-sy could be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for one of those?

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=axis A,
grid=major,
]
\addplot[samples=10,domain=0:2]{x^2-2};
\end{axis}
\begin{scope}[xshift=8em,yshift=-20em]
\begin{axis}[name=axis B,
grid=major,
]
\addplot[samples=10,domain=-3:2]{-x^2+2};
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\draw[red,thick] (axis A.north east) -- (axis B.north east)
(axis A.south west) -- (axis B.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=major,
]
\addplot[samples=10,domain=0:2]{x^2-2};
\draw (0,-2) coordinate (bl) rectangle (1,2) coordinate (tr);
\end{axis}
\begin{scope}[xshift=8em,yshift=-20em]
\begin{axis}[name=axis B,
grid=major,
]
\addplot[samples=10,domain=-3:2]{-x^2+2};
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\draw[red,thick] (tr) -- (axis B.north east)
(bl) -- (axis B.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well that looks quite promising. Tell me, where the nodes `bl` and `tr` are first defined?

Comment: @tush `\draw (0,-2) coordinate (bl) rectangle (1,2) coordinate (tr);`

Comment: So `bl` is defined to be at `(0,-2)` and the same for `tr` to be at `(1,2)`?

Comment: @tush precisely. The other corners are "known" because I gave the `axis` objects names, so they are just rectangular nodes the anchors of which one can use.

Comment: If you are already on the track, can you show me how to start the inset of the upper plot (+x^2 parabola) to start from somewhere in the middle of its canvas, as demonstrated in the original post?

Comment: @tush `\draw (0.5,-2) coordinate (bl) rectangle (1.5,2) coordinate (tr);`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123904/discussion-between-tush-and-user241266).

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I imported my underlying graphs as images, so you could focus on the syntax of the `\stackinset`, where I place argument `#5` (the "spy" boxes) atop argument `#6` (the underlying graphics), in this case, aligned at the bottom-right corner.  However, you could replace each of the `\includegraphics` calls with (in this case 3cm x 3cm) tikz drawings, or you could create them in `standalone` mode and import them, as I do here.

The key is to lay out the two images in a size you like, and that will provide you the graph coordinates to use for your "spy" boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,stackengine}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{r}{}{b}{}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick] (1,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,3) -- (1,3) -- (1,0);
\draw [thick] (.25,4) -- (.75,4) -- (.75,6) -- (.25,6) -- (.25,4);
\draw [thick] (.25,4) -- (1,0);
\draw [thick] (.75,6) -- (4,3);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}{%
  \stackon[.5cm]
    {\kern1cm\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-a}}%
    {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-b}\kern1cm}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the OP's sample graph, I could adapt.  However, I highly recommend setting your graph up in a way where you know exact size of your images.  Further, while both graphs are done in a single `tikz` picture, it may prove simpler to stack them as two separate `tikz` constructions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{r}{.2cm}{b}{.5cm}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick] (3.3,0) -- (10,0) -- (10,5.5) -- (3.3,5.5) -- (3.3,0);
\draw [thick] (.5,7.0) -- (2,7.0) -- (2,8.5) -- (.5,8.5) -- (.5,7.0);
\draw [thick] (.5,7.0) -- (3.3,0);
\draw [thick] (2,8.5) -- (10,5.5);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
grid=major,
]
\addplot[samples=10,domain=0:2]{x^2-2};
\end{axis}
\begin{scope}[xshift=8em,yshift=-20em]
\begin{axis}[
grid=major,
]
\addplot[samples=10,domain=-3:2]{-x^2+2};
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\draw[red,thick] (0,0) -- (2,1); % <--- A decoration
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since this drawing is going to be included in a rather long project, ~35 pages in length, with some other 25 or so drawing, I rather prefer to keep my self the ability to save, and include, this graphics as a `tikz` file. Is it possible with your solution? Moreover, these waveforms to be plotted are generated from csv lists, with the horizontal axis meaning time, so I want the decorations to be drawn through the axis coordinates. This is the reason for my tendency to use `(axis cs:_,_)` in the original post. I think that I will write down all that information.

Comment: @tush I am not a `tikz` expert and so I can't really answer your questions off the cuff (I am not sure what you mean by "`tikz` file").  I see you provided sample code to create two sample graph  I will work to  show how it is done with my method.

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat.